# Scala sbt AutoPlugin with dependencies. Error while enablePlugins in another project

Tags: scala, plugins, sbt

I'm trying to workaround creating sbt AutoPlugins.
I want to create plugin which will autoloading all his dependencies, so I use NoTrigger policy.
I wrote my own AutoPlugin which must execute assembly task from sbt-assembly and look like:

settings in ***/build.sbt***

```
name := "sbt-myplugin"
version := "0.0.1"
organization := "com.org"
scalaVersion := "2.10.6"
sbtPlugin := true
sbtVersion := "0.13.11"

addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.3")
```

plugin code in ***/src/main/scala/myplugin/MyPlugin.scala***

```
package myplugin

import sbt._
import sbtassembly.AssemblyPlugin
import sbtassembly.AssemblyPlugin.autoImport._

object MyPlugin extends AutoPlugin{
  override def trigger = noTrigger
  override def requires = AssemblyPlugin

  object autoImport {
    val myAssembly = taskKey[File]("Assembled file")
  }

  import autoImport._
  override lazy val projectSettings = Seq(
    myAssembly := assembly.value
  )
}
```

Then i'm create artifact with **sbt clean compile publishLocal**
After this I created test project which will use my plugin.

settings for this project in ***/project/plugins.sbt***

```
logLevel := Level.Warn

resolvers += "Local Ivy Repository" at "file://"+Path.userHome.absolutePath+"/.ivy2/local"
addSbtPlugin("com.academmedia.ias" % "sbt-pkplace" % "0.0.1")
```

settings in ***/biuld.sbt***

```
name := "test-project"
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(myplugin.MyPlugin)
```

Now I'm expecting able to use `MyPlugin` task *myAssembly* but my project `sbt` is unable to download project settings with error:

```
[error] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sbtassembly/AssemblyPlugin$
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks for answer!

Comment: Check the paths that you wrote. Are you sure the plugin source is in `src/scala/myplugin/`? not `src/scala/main/myplugin/`?

Comment: Real path is `/src/main/scala/myplugin/MyPlugin.scala`. I'm just made a typo.